# Solve system of equations with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Very trivial question but I'd terrible at linear algebra. Suppose I have 4 unknowns with 4 equations. For example, the Gaussian Quadrature, exact for polynomials of degree 3 or less. That is.

$$A_0 + A_1 = 2$$
$$A_0x_0 + A_1x_1 = 0$$
$$A_0x_0^2 + A_1x_1^2 = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$A_0x_0^3 + A_1x_1^3 = 0$$

How can I proceed to solve for $A_0, A_1, x_0, x_1$ without doing middle school plugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that these are *not* linear equations (because you have terms that are up to fourth total exponent) so there is no way to solve them using a matrix or linear algebra.

There are methods that can solve arbitrary polynomial equations (to start your path down the rabbit-hole, use the keyword "Groebner basis") but they are not simple, efficient, or easy to use. Careful "middle school" elimination is probably the best approach for your specific set of equations.

For example subtract $x_0^2$ times the second equation from the third to get
$$A_1x_1(x_1^2-x_0^2)=0$$
and notice that $A_1=0$ and $x_1=0$ both do not lead to a solution. So 
$$x_1=\pm x_0.$$
If $x_1=x_0$ the first two equations have no solution, so $x_1=-x_0$. Plug into the first two equations to get $A_0=A_1=1.$ Plug into the third equation to get $x_0 = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, x_1 = \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$